# My app was rejected due to REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES

Tags: google-play-services, android-manifest, google-play-console, policy

Due to Google's new policy, my app was not approved. Here is the reply i got

> We’re reaching out in response to your recent appeal regarding enforcement of your app. We are unable to approve your app’s use of REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission because the use of the permission is not directly related to the core purpose of the app.

I have tried the workaround I found on starkoverflow. Like adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" tools:node="remove" />
```

But I don't see it working because I can still see the REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES permission still listed in the manifest merger debug report. Which will eventually make them reject the app again
If anyone can assist, I would be grateful.

Comment: The merged manifest in Android studio should show you what library introduces this permission

Comment: yes thank you. I think i got this sorted now